# C++ ad-hoc "requires" expressions in template default argument yield error with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, c++20, c++-concepts

Compiling the following code with GCC 10.2 ...

```
template<typename T, bool = requires(T const& x){ x.foo(); }>
struct foo;
int main() {}
```

... yields the following [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad9f75f9e78f0203):

```
main.cpp:1:51: error: local variable 'x' may not appear in this context
    1 | template<typename T, bool = requires(T const& x){ x.foo(); }>
      |                                                   ^
```

However, changing the requires expression to `requires(T const& x){ std::declval<T const&>().foo(); }` solves this issue. Why is that?

Comment: Compiles with [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/xx3xxh).

Comment: I think this is just a GCC bug similar to [94499](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94499).